# Работа с изображением с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript

На экране задано изображение. Написать сценарий, позволяющий изменять размеры рисунка, его границу (данные вводятся пользователем).

Comment: Пример вашего кода?

Comment: "На экране задано изображение." - ???

Comment: Для взятия части изображения на JavaScript можно использовать специальные библиотеки.

Ключевыми словоми для их поиска является "JavaScript image crop".

Вот пример одной из них - http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Предполагаю что вы имели ввиду это. Если вы имели ввиду обрезать картинку, есть хороший [урок](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/)

```js
var width = document.getElementById("width");
var height = document.getElementById("height");
var image = document.getElementById("image");

width.oninput = function() {
  var value = parseInt(width.value);
  if (typeof(value) == 'number') {
    image.style.width = value + "px";
  }
};
height.oninput = function() {
  var value = parseInt(height.value);
  if (typeof(value) == 'number') {
    image.style.height = value + "px";
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="width" placeholder="width" />
  <input type="text" id="height" placeholder="height" />
</div>
<div>
  <img id="image" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="http://wac.2f9ad.chicdn.net/802F9AD/u/joyent.wme/public/wme/assets/ec050984-7b81-11e6-96e0-8905cd656caf.jpg?v=54" />
</div>
```